# Application recognize empty edit tex as 0

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I am making calculator with 2 activities. In first activity i have 3 edit text.  And here is my problem becouse when  I don't introduce any value to edit text and i wanna go to next activity my application stops working . So how to do that when i will not put any value to editext application will recognize it as 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#strip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) to remove all leading and trailing whitespace from the text of the `EditText` and if the length is 0 after doing so, the `EditText` is empty.

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
final String text = editText.getText().toString();
final int num;
if(text.strip().isEmpty()){
    num = 0;
} else {
    num = Integer.parseInt(text);
}
```

A safer way to do this would be to try using [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) to get the numeric value of the text of the `EditText`. It will throw a [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the String cannot be parsed as a number, which you can catch and then set the number to 0.

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
final String text = editText.getText().toString();
int num;
try{
   num = Integer.parseInt(text);
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
   num = 0;
}
```